# Zope (Page Template), Ajax/Javascript and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ajax, zope, template-tal, zpt

I have 2 chained list :

```
<select>
<option> Half Life </option>
<option> Mario </option>
          ...
</select>

<select>
<option> Gordon </option>
<option> Alexia </option>
<option> Peach </option>
<option> Luigi </option>
          ...
</select>
```

These selects are populated by MySQL requests (ZSQL Method)

I would like to load this second form only when it's necessary. I don't know how to do in a Zope Page Template to link these select dynamically (Certainly with AJAX and JAVASCRIPT?). So I search in some topics but I don't find examples..

(I find these topics, but I don't know how to operate : [dynamicly fill table using zpt and ajax as update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545153/dynamicly-fill-table-using-zpt-and-ajax-as-update); http://play.pixelblaster.ro/blog/topics/AJAX ; http://zajax.net/)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) in the form page:

```
$("#first_select").click(function(){
    var dat_game = $('#first_select option:selected').text();
    $.post("a_new_page_template", { dat_game: dat_game},
    function(data){         
        var $response=$(data);
        var res = $response.filter('#whatiwant').html();
        $('#second_select').append(res);
    });
    return false;
});
```

2) in the 'a_new_page_template':

```
  <html>
   <body tal:define="results  here/sql_select_value;                          
                      start request/start|python:0;                                                       
                      batch python:modules['ZTUtils'].Batch(results,                                      
                      size=50,                                                                        
                      start=start)"> 
    <span id="whatiwant">
      <tal:x repeat="result batch">
       <option><tal:x replace="result/value">value goes here</tal:x></option>
      </tal:x>
    </span>   
   </body>
  </html>
```

Thanks to me :)